# Laravel merge to object and create pagination from that

Tags: php, laravel

with this codes i can get all records from tables. but i want to merge this objects and create paginate from that, for example:

```
$total_legal_users = AccountLeaglUsers::all();
$total_real_users = AccountRealUsers::all();
```

create paginate, for example:

```
$total = $total_legal_users + $total_real_users;
$total->paginate(50);
```

how to do that?

My Test:

```
$results = $total_legal_users->union($total_real_users)->paginate(50);
```

but i get error for `union`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually create a paginator.

```
$total_legal_users = AccountLeaglUsers::all()->toArray();
$total_real_users = AccountRealUsers::all()->toArray();
$total = array_merge($total_legal_users, $total_real_users);
$perPage = 15;
$paginator = new Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator($total, perPage);
```

And read about it more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)

Comment: i get error: `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int`